# Try to have something echo in a sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to "echo" something in a SQL query.

I noticed this does not work:

```
$usernames = echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');  
$file = $_GET['file'];


$sql="INSERT INTO bekeken(username, filename)VALUES(".$usernames.", '".$fileloc."')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

The echo thingy works perfect, it echoes the username how it should.

But now i want to insert that username in the database together with a filename that is received with a PHP GET.

I guess i am doing a lot wrong, but i dont see it.

Thanks in advance!

Mark

FullCode:

```
  mysql_connect("localhost", "movidz", "password!") or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("movidz") or die(mysql_error());

  $file = $_GET['file'];

  $sql_scale = "SELECT * FROM films WHERE filename = '".$file."'";
  $result_scale = mysql_query($sql_scale)or die(mysql_error());

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_scale)){$titel=$row['titel'];}
  echo "<div class='player_filmtitel_div'><h1 class='player_filmtitel'>".$titel."</h1></div>";
```

Comment: Is all of that code enclosed in php tags?

Comment: Did you connect to your database? before writing a `INSERT` Statement?

Comment: Yes it is enclosed in the PHP tags :)

Comment: And yes, there is a MySQL connect between the same php tags.

Comment: I Edited the main post.

Comment: What is this `'".$file."'"` spouse to be?

Comment: '".$file."'" means a filename that is received trough a PHP GET

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting `$fileloc` but you are defining `$file`.

```
$usernames = echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');  
$fileloc = $_GET['file']; // changed $file to $fileloc


$sql="INSERT INTO bekeken(username, filename)VALUES(".$usernames.", '".$fileloc."')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

As is, you're setting a variable equal to `echo htmlentities(...)`. There is no need to echo it because `htmlentities()` already returns a string. You can echo it afterwards if desired. echo is only used to display what is echoed in plain html. So your code should look something like this:

```
$usernames = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');  
$file = $_GET['file'];


$sql="INSERT INTO bekeken(username, filename) VALUES('{$usernames}', '{$file}')";
$result=mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
```

Your quotations were way off, in addition to using an undefined $fileloc. Also, I would suggest using `mysqli_`

Comment: Hi, i dont need to echo it at all, that was just a test. I just need it to write the username to the database, further the only thing i know is that the `htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');` works.

Comment: @user3915031 The rest of my answer should still be relevant. There were a lot of things wrong with your code and it should help out.